# Predicting how long a method takes to run java

Tags: java, performance, loading, game-engine, prediction

Is it possible to predict how long a method will take to run?? Since every machine has different abilities in terms of performance, I want to be able to predict how long it takes to load up my game, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define the steps needed to bootstrap your application
2. Measure (at runtime) the time between them - you could use [Codahale Metrics](http://metrics.codahale.com/) or even `System.currentTimeMillis()` to track both start and end
3. Calculate remaining time according the average time elapsed between steps.
4. Guesstimate it :) As you might already know, you can't be 100% precise about it (most installers don't get it right)

Another approach is to define certain percentages for each completed step. Something like:

- [30%] init gui
- [50%] connect to database
- [70%] execute query
- [90%] parse results

Comment: Thanks, I'm probably going to take this: 
[30%] init gui
[50%] connect to database
[70%] execute query
[90%] parse results
Approach.

Answer (score 2):

I guess he needs it in order to display a progress bar. I assume, again, that he wants to know how long it will run so he can display the progress on the progress bar based on the time interval.

I suggest doing something else:

- in the loading code insert some position markers
- progress bar should be informed when the loading hits those markers and display percentage of the code that has been executed so far

I suggest using the [*Observer pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Answer (score -1):

Since computers may perform thousands of tasks at a given time, it is impossible to estimate the execution time of something.

Saying that, it is not impossible to measure it at all. Since you are using java, try measuring execution time in milliseconds:

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

You can then process this information anyway you want. Probably using a Log file would be great, so you can then put even more information about the running environment on it.